# Can I use iPad/Airport/Mac Mini as a development network?

Tags: ipad, mac-mini, network

I am thinking of getting a Mac Mini as an inexpensive development server. I want to install MySql and get up and running quickly. Can I :

1. Use my existing AirPort to create a wireless LAN so that my Windows PC can use the Mac Mini as a database server?
2. Use my existing iPad to remote access the Mac Mini so I can install and configure the MySql instance?

If anyone knew of any books or documentation of how to do this, that would be cool.

Comment: Do you need MySql - could you use postgres - if so the Apple Server will have it mostly set up for you

Comment: Well, the server that I will rent when I get the dev project up and running will probably be Linux with either SQLite or MySql, so I will stick to those. Also, MySQL is easier from a Windows client, so will stick with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new Mini is most likely 'enough' computer, but you also have options as to which OS you run on it.

Do you intend to run your development server on OSX?  You could also run Windows or Linux either natively or virtually.  Given the myriad options, I'm sure it's possible to do what you're looking to do.

Your AirPort will allow communication between the Windows PC and the Mini.

As far as the iPad goes, *there's and app for that*.  I've personally used the Teamviewer app and the RealVNC app.  Both have served me well.

Comment: This will only be to get up and running. Once I get the development up and running I'll just rent a server and run the MySql on Linux.

Comment: IMHO it will be cheaper to have the Mac Mini run the MySQL than rent a server. Your Mac Mini offers a fixed, one time cost (though you do pay for electricity) whereas renting the server is an on-going expense.